# Angular ui router - Transistion from one state to same state without parameters fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Csur2)

```
  <script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
     myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard")

      $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
          url: '/dashboard',
          templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'

        })
        .state('verify', {
          url: '/verify?email&code',
          templateUrl: 'verify.html',
          controller: 'verifyCtrl'
        })
    });
    myapp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$state) {
      $scope.goTo = function () {
        $state.go('verify',{'email':'param@test.com', 'code': {'name': 'test name'}});
      }
    })
    myapp.controller('verifyCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
      $scope.email = $stateParams.email;
      $scope.code = $stateParams.code.name;
    })
  </script>
```

When navigating from a state that was transitioned with parameter to same state without parameter,its not working.

In the demo click on "verify with email & code" first and then other link "verify without params". It will not navigate correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The State properties are usually inherited when in transition from one state to another.This causes the params to be copied too if they are not defined.Using `inherit=false` will stop this.
For using this option in ui-serf we have the `ui-sref-opts` attribute.

[Demo-Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Ya2f4YuTW3SXGEcBI9T)

**In HTML:**

```
<a ui-sref="verify" ui-sref-opts="{inherit: false}">verify without params</a>
```

**In JS:**

```
$state.go('verify',{},{inherit:false});
```

Comment: No, This is not my question

I need to navigate to state with paramater to without parameter and vice versa "http://plnkr.co/edit/IDjxWhO1mP1bsDCyEBef?p=preview". See,Your Angular not working with updated one

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean when saying " with paramater to without parameter " using your page as examples?My understanding is that you want to move to state verify with or without params.

Comment: Yes, Sure

I'm on the link/state (Active)
http://run.plnkr.co/Hk0zba9O2y3Js4rj/#/verify

If I like to change to same link/state with params
http://run.plnkr.co/Hk0zba9O2y3Js4rj/#/verify?email=mail2asik@gmail.com

It's Not Changing the View.

Comment: So Initially you move to state verify with say email:test1@tt and then again you want to move to same state verify with different params say email:test2@tt but your values are not getting updated.Is that your issue?

Comment: Yes, Right, This is my issue

Comment: Updated answer after understanding your requirement.

Comment: Works like Charm. Hey mate, is that possible for you to share how do you get information like this? Because from my points view, it wouldn't be possible if you have gone through the source code yourself.

Comment: @TypingPanda Always google first.If that doesn't give you an answer then read the [docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.4.2/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).If even that fails,check the source code or raise a question in SO or github.